# How to auto connect to VPN upon login/boot?

Tags: macos, vpn, login, internet

So far, I've been using the build-in VPN tool of Lion.

I would like to auto connect my VPN whenever I'm connected to the internet.

**Is it possible to auto connect my VPN whenever I'm connected to the internet with the build in tool?**

If auto connect is not possible with the build in tool, can you provide me with an alternative that is free?

Comment: Isn't there an option for this under "Advanced" in Network Settings? I don't have my Mac with me.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Viscocity, the Open VPN client?

Comment: @christian Good question! I don't know. I've asked their support via [Twitter](http://twitter.com/sparklabs) and have not yet received an answer. But you can try to get a solution in their [forum](http://www.sparklabs.com/forum/). So far, I've been using the amazing [Shimo](http://www.chungwasoft.com/shimo/) VPN client which supports OpenVPN and has this feature build in. However, this does not answer your question :).

Comment: @christian The latest version of Viscosity has a setting for this. When you select a VPN profile and edit it, there is an option at the bottom to start this VPN service when Viscosity starts.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Apple Script** provides a good solution:

```
on idle
    tell application "System Events"
        tell current location of network preferences
            set myConnection to the service "VPN University"
            if myConnection is not null then
                if current configuration of myConnection is not connected then
                    connect myConnection
                end if
            end if
        end tell
        return 120
    end tell
end idle
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Great! Worked like a charm. I'm using Lion 10.7.2.

Comment: still working perfectly on 10.12.3

Comment: Found via lifehacker: https://lifehacker.com/force-mac-os-x-to-automatically-reconnect-to-vpn-5932886

Comment: This doesn't work for me on 10.14.6 ... I get an error message saying : "Can’t get «class svce» "ProtonVPN" of «class locc» of «class netp» of application "System Events". System Events got an error: Can’t get service "ProtonVPN" of current location of network preferences. (-1728) " ... ProtonVPN just happens to be the name that I assigned to my VPN connection in System Preferences. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: @nckbrzg check permission is allowed for your script app to access System Events.app in Prefs > Security > Privacy > Automation > your app > System Events.app checked

Answer (score 8):

Another way to go about this, is by creating a Configuration Profile (using [Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?l=en&mt=12)). Using this tool, recreate your VPN configuration and save the file. After you've created the file, open it up in a text editor and look for the following:

```
<key>VPNType</key>
<value>(...)</key>
```

Add the following below:

```
<key>OnDemandEnabled</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>OnDemandRules</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Action</key>
        <string>Connect</string>
        <key>InterfaceTypeMatch</key>
        <string>WiFi</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Action</key>
        <string>Connect</string>
        <key>InterfaceTypeMatch</key>
        <string>Cellular</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Now after you've installed this profile, a checkbox "Connect on demand" should be shown in the "Network" system preferences. Now macOS will keep your connection alive. Bonus feature: you can also add specific rules about when the VPN should connect or disconnect, depending on which Wifi network you're connected.

See [Configuration Profile Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW36) on Apple's Developer Site for all on-demand rules. And see also the [strongSwan wiki](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/AppleIKEv2Profile#Enable-On-Demand-VPN) where some examples are shown.