# Running terminal commands on startup/login

Tags: terminal, startup, login-items

How can I run terminal commands on startup or login? On FreeBSD I believe you can [do this using rc.d](http://osresources.com/2_10_en.html) - is there an equivalent for the Mac? I know how to set up Login Items, but these only work for GUI applications, and there must be an elegant way to make terminal commands run without wrapping them in a GUI executable? As clarified below, I sometimes need to sudo these commands.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run/stop/relaunch an application automatically, at boot/login/some other time?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/how-can-i-run-stop-relaunch-an-application-automatically-at-boot-login-some-oth)

Comment: Not really a duplicate, as it's specific to terminal commands, covering how to sudo them, etc.

Comment: This question is "How can I run terminal commands on startup or login? " as is the other and where is sudo in either question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OSX uses [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/launchd.8.html) to start Unix scripts and executables at boot or login.

New tasks are added via [launchctl](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/launchctl.1.html) to update a [plist](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/launchd.plist)

An easier way of doing this is to use the app [Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) now available on the Mac App Store or [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/)

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at Lingon!

Comment: Thanks, how would I go about adding a command starting 'sudo' via launchctl (given I'd need to supply my sudo password)?

Comment: @tog22 in the plist see the key UserName to say which user the command should run as

Comment: You can run launchd services as root by saving them to `/Library/`.

Answer (score 2):

Use **Apple Script**.

The script would be like this:

> `do shell script "cd ~/Documents"`

Create an application that uses this script. This application can be added to the login items. I've explained in detail how to do this [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32392/auto-connect-vpn-upon-login-boot).

**Executing commands in Apple Script as admin**

Password prompt at runtime:

> `do shell script "rm -rf ~/Documents/Gorleben" with administrator privileges`

Password saved within the script:

> `do shell script "rm -rf ~/Documents/Gorleben" with administrator privileges password "123456"`

Comment: Thanks, but I need to 'sudo' my command - presumably there's no way to do that with AppleScript as I'd need to enter my password after the command?

Comment: This can be done by adding ``with administrator privileges password "123456"`` at the end of the command. If you don't want to save the password in the script, just write ``with administrator privileges``. Then you'll be prompted for a password at runtime. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

On mac, executing some script after startup can be accomplished by cron job:

```
@reboot /path/to/script.sh
```