# Reconnect to VPN automatically

Tags: macos, network, vpn

I have a Softether VPN server v2.00-9387, which is OpenVPN compatible. I am connecting to it via L2TP protocol on my Windows 7 and Mac OS X 10.9.5 computers, using built-in network connections, without any problem.

I want this connection to reconnect automatically whenever it is dropped on my Mac. For this purpose I created an Apple script using the instructions which can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32392/how-to-auto-connect-to-vpn-upon-login-boot/32395#32395). However I get following error upon running the script:

```
Can't get <<class svce>> "VPN" of <<class locc>> of <<class netp>> of application "System Events".
```

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: That won't work with IKEv2 VPNs. Here's how you can do that: http://matt.coneybeare.me/how-to-setup-an-auto-reconnect-script-for-an-ikev2-vpn -service-on-your-mac/

Comment: I also want this. Whenever I take my work laptop home I have to click it, wait, and half the time it doesn't connect. If I could just have it do it until it succeeds that would allow me to leave my time and attention for more important things.